# AngularJS - after revving js script, browser still load old js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I develop very big and complex web app with angular on front. I often do change, because the application is running in test phase now. For all script and css I use gulp concat and minify, and in product mode I have only one script.js with all js, and one main.css with all css. The problem began when I went on a daily basis to make changes, and if I put into production, customer get old scripts from the cache. They should make HARD REFRESH for the new changes, but it is very boring and not practical. So I started working with a gulp revving,and now i generated always new version number, like `script.js --> script-79879879.js and for main.css --> main-46489498.css` . Unfortunately this did not solve my problem, the browser continues to load old scripts from the cache. Please if anyone has advice. Thank you, and excuse my bad English

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Fountain](http://fountainjs.io) along with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) and save time in creating your gulp setup . It comes with all versioning, minifying and stuff required for pushing something to production.

In your case here , make sure that the `index.html` that is loaded is the latest all the time . You can add `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">` to set the expiry for your index.html . There would also be ways to handle the lifetime of the index.html at your server, You will have to specify the least age for it .

Comment: thnx for suggesting for Fountain, but if I understand, this is for starting a new app, if I try to use Fountain in my app, I need change bunch of code. For meta tag, I already use this <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />. But this not help

Comment: Yeah , fountain gives the basic boilerplate for a production ready app. Is your index.html cached too ?